# Defining a class abstract and using its implementation in a different project, what java package name should be used?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, package, abstract-class

E.g. I have

project X
with class `a.b.c.d.AbstractFoo`

now I have project Y with an implementation of `AbstractFoo`

Is there a convention on using package names? Is there an advantage, if say, the package names are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***Is there a convention on using package names?***

The package name of the implementation of `AbstractFoo` should make sense for *that* class, and should not necessarily be the same as the package of `AbstractFoo`.

I for instance often override / implement `JComponent`, still I wouldn't dream of writing `package javax.swing` in one of my source files.

> ***Is there an advantage, if say, the package names are the same?***

No, not really. There is a semantical difference though, and that is due to the default (package level) access modifier. Relying on that the package name of one project matches the package name of another project seems like a really bad idea to me though.

Answer (score 1):

don't use same packages in different projects. it's easy to fall into a name collision in a future. each project should have it's own namespace so you can put both projects on the classpath without any name collision. if you have com.yourcompany.projectA.List interface i would use something like com.yourcompany.listCommons.AbstractList class. there is no standards. naming just should be readable and understandable for others

Answer (score 0):

For different projects/JARs use different package names. You will save yourself and others lots of time later.